# Orgmode Table Formatting of Cells

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-table

I have an Emacs org mode table that looks like this:

```
 |--------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------|
 | <20>                           | <60>                                                 |
 | How do you alter your password | The command to alter your password in oracle is::    |
 | in Oracle?                     |                                                      |
 |                                |     ALTER USER {userid} IDENTIFIED BY {password};    |
 |                                |                                                      |
 |--------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------|
```

When the table is resized with `C-c C-c` i.e. with keyboard shortcut: `Ctrl-C + Ctrl-C`, or automatically, it ruins the spacing inside of the table elements and I get:

```
 |--------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------|
 | <20>                           | <60>                                                 |
 | How do you alter your password | The command to alter your password in oracle is::    |
 | in Oracle?                     |                                                      |
 |                                | ALTER USER {userid} IDENTIFIED BY {password};        |
 |                                |                                                      |
 |--------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------|
```

It automatically trims the leading spaces from the content in the table.  Is there a way to prevent this in org mode tables?  I want org mode to not change the formatting of the content.

This is with Emacs version `24.3.50`, but the behavior is the same in version `24.2` (I tried in both versions).

Comment: Try automatic alignment of number-rich columns to the right http://orgmode.org/manual/Column-width-and-alignment.html

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and it right aligns all text.  That's not what I was trying to do.  I was hoping there would be a way for it to not do any formatting of the contents.

Comment: What about using non-breakable spaces? Org mode does not touch them.

Comment: It works. `C-x 8 SPC` is for inserting such spaces.

Comment: I'm using a sightly different approach for the task you're doing: put questions as links in the table, and answers as headings. Example at: https://gist.github.com/abo-abo/6040382

Answer (score 0):

A really hack-ish way to work around it is to redefine or defadvice around org-table-align. The relevant snippet is roughly around here. By changing * to ?, you'll keep the spaces at the beginning.

```
--- ./org-table.el
+++ ./org-table.el.orig
@@ -752,7 +752,7 @@
     ;; Get the data fields by splitting the lines.
     (setq fields (mapcar
          (lambda (l)
-           (org-split-string l " *| *"))
+           (org-split-string l " *| ?"))
          (delq nil (copy-sequence lines))))
     ;; How many fields in the longest line?
     (condition-case nil
```

I'm not sure if you really want to do that, though. Would you consider restructuring your markup, perhaps by using headings instead, with a custom markup function in case you really need it to look like tables afterwards? If that makes you boggle, another way to accomplish that might be with #+BEGIN_HTML and #+END_HTML blocks. Not elegant, but ah well...